# AspectJ does not weave JUnit classes when built with Ant

Tags: java, ant, aspectj

I have created an aspect with AspectJ, to build it and weave my classes during compile time with it I use ANT  task. I have also created test class that is intended to test how  that aspect works. Here is the problem: my test classes are not being weaved. And I do not why.
My source folder is src/main/java and my test folder is src/test/java
When I move my test class to the source folder everything works fine..

Update 1: I am not using AspectJ in conjunction with Spring. Also I am not using aop.xml, my aspects are being annotated.

Update 2: my ant compile-aspectj-tests target looks like this:

```
<target name="compile-aspectj-tests" depends="compile">
        <taskdef resource="org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${ivy.install.dir}/../cache/org.aspectj/aspectjtools/jars/aspectjtools-1.7.3.jar" />
            </classpath> 
        </taskdef> 
        <iajc srcDir="${test.dir}/java" destDir="${compiled.tests}" debug="on" Xlintwarnings="true" 
            showWeaveInfo="true" source="${targetVersion}" target="${targetVersion}" >
            <classpath>
                <path refid="test.classpath" />
                <pathelement location="${compiled.src}" />
            </classpath>
            <aspectpath location="${compiled.src}" />
        </iajc>
    </target>
```

This is what I see in the console:

```
compile-aspectj-tests:
     [iajc] warning at com/.../cache/aspects/RetryJedisConnectionExceptionAspect.java::0 no match for this type name: RetryJedisConnectionException [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565490/ignoring-aspectj-during-junit-tests

Comment: No, this is different since I am not using AspectJ in conjunction with Spring. Also I am not using aop.xml, my aspects are being annotated.

Comment: Maybe that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702208/simple-ant-build-script-that-supports-src-and-test?

Comment: @Rankel: sorry, but the link you suggested has nothing to do with AspectJ.

Comment: Is `RetryJedisConnectionException` on the test classpath?

Comment: Yes, it is on the classpath